# Why is my output for nominal_test incomplete?

Tags: ordinal-data, proportional-hazards

I am currently using the nominal_test function, in the ordinal package, to test for the proportional odds assumption but have encountered a problem.

Here is my code:

```
feelingsmodel<-clm(Feelings ~ 
                     Gender + 
                     Location + 
                     Role + 
                     FarmType + 
                     Age + 
                     Income + 
                     Knowledge, 
                   data = data, na.action=na.exclude, Hess = TRUE , link = "logit")

nominal_test(feelingsmodel)
```

And my output:

```
Tests of nominal effects

formula: Feelings ~ Gender + Location + Role + FarmType + Age + Income + Knowledge
          Df  logLik    AIC     LRT Pr(>Chi)  
<none>       -629.12 1320.2                   
Gender     5 -625.92 1323.8  6.3829  0.27073  
Location                                      
Role      15 -627.18 1346.3  3.8806  0.99810  
FarmType                                      
Age       15 -618.83 1329.7 20.5712  0.15110  
Income    10 -617.82 1317.6 22.5870  0.01238 *

Knowledge
```

For some explanatory variables (Location, FarmType and Knowledge) there seems to be no output. When I run similar models different output for different explanatory variables is omitted seemingly at random. How I could solve this problem and get a p value for all explanatory variables?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Jack Shepherd-Cross. What is your sample size? Do you have any residual degrees of freedom? If you do not, that would mean that you had insufficient degrees of freedom to fit coefficients for your explanatory variables, which could be the reason for the problem. Check the output for 'clm' as well, and make sure you have 'warnings' messages turned on, as they may give you some hints as to where any problems might lie.

Comment: @Izy Thanks for your reply. My sample size is 603 so I doubt sample size is the problem. Warning messages are turned on and clm output seems to be ok! All seems a but strange. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit old but maybe someone is still interested in an answer (as I was myself).

The output remains incomplete for a model term, if the model fails to converge when this term is moved to `nominal` in the `clm` call (i.e., when the model is refitted as partial proportional odds, to test the proportional odds assumption).

To provide a very succint example:

```
# This is our model
m1 <- clm(rating ~ x1 + x2, data = mdata)

# To check the proportional odds assumption we can use `nominal_test`
#   as a shortcut for the following:
m2 <- clm(rating ~ x2, data = mdata, nominal = ~ x1)
m3 <- clm(rating ~ x1, data = mdata, nominal = ~ x2)
anova(m1, m2)
anova(m2, m3)
```

The problem is that "[w]ith many nominal effects it may be difficult to find a model in which the threshold parameters are strictly increasing for all combinations of the parameters." ([Christensen, 2018](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/vignettes/clm_article.pdf))

The increase of threshold parameters is checked during model fiting. If this criterion is not met, the model is considered invalid and no likelihood ratio tests are conducted, which explains why the lines corresponding to some factors remain blank.

To check what exactly happens with your model, you can investigate the `nominal_test` function by running `debugonce(nominal_test)` and then `nominal_test(feelingsmodel)`. You'll then have to press enter to pass each line of the function's source code. After running the line `nfit <- try(update(object, nominal = nomforms[[i]], convergence = "silent"), silent = TRUE)` you can interactively inspect the nfit object, which holds the modified model (term moved to `nominal`). `nfit$convergence` will give you the convergence code which you can compare with the ones listed in the [paper introducing the `ordinal` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/vignettes/clm_article.pdf).

If you obtain a convergence code of -3, which I suspect, then it is indeed a problem of non-increasing threshold parameters and you may try what the author of the package and paper suggests:

> When a continuous variable is included among the nominal effects it is often helpful if thecontinuous variable is centered at an appropriate value (at least within the observed range of the data).

However, I suppose that your variable `FarmType`, for example, is not continuous but I can't tell what you're supposed to do then nor what the failure to assess proportionality of odds in this way means for the reliability of your model...